# How to use R packages MACD functions?

Tags: r, finance, quantmod

I am learning to use R. I have an interest in pulling stock data and calculating various technical indicators on the stock data. My test benchmark is Google Finance. That is, I check my results with GF's results.

While trying to implement some sort of MACD analysis, I have noticed a couple of things. These are probably my misinterpretation of the documentation. I have tried many variations and I cannot get agreement with Google Finance's numbers in some cases.

`library(quantmod)` gives me `MACD()`, which returns columns `macd` and `signal`.

`library(fTrading)` gives me `cdsTA()` and `cdoTA()`, which return `cdsTA` and `cdoTA` respectively.

My test stock is IBM, and hopefully this link will pull up a chart with prices, volume, slow stochastics and MACD with histogram.

http://www.google.com//finance?chdnp=1&chdd=1&chds=1&chdv=1&chvs=Linear&chdeh=0&chfdeh=0&chdet=1298224745682&chddm=46920&chddi=86400&chls=CandleStick&q=NYSE:IBM&ntsp=0

Loading up IBM's price data into R and generating the values of the 3 functions above for the values 8, 17, 9 and for `MACD()` I set `percent=FALSE` gives me the following output.

```
MACD(close, 8, 17, 9, maType="EMA", percent=FALSE)
cdsTA(close, lag1 = 8, lag2 = 17, lag3 = 9)
cdoTA(close, lag1 = 8, lag2 = 17, lag3 = 9)

      date     close     macd   signal      cdsTA      cdoTA
2011-02-07    164.17 3.187365 3.208984   3.208984 -0.7673435
2011-02-08    166.05 3.246812 3.216549   3.216549 -0.7996041
2011-02-09    164.65 3.052187 3.183677   3.183677 -1.0496306
2011-02-10    164.09 2.780047 3.102951   3.102951 -1.3332292
2011-02-11    163.85 2.496591 2.981679   2.981679 -1.5867962
2011-02-14    163.22 2.168977 2.819138   2.819138 -1.8408138
2011-02-15    162.84 1.846701 2.624651   2.624651 -2.0507546
2011-02-16    163.40 1.640518 2.427824   2.427824 -2.1262626
2011-02-17    164.24 1.550798 2.252419   2.252419 -2.0854783
2011-02-18    164.84 1.517145 2.105364   2.105364 -1.9968608
```

If you refer to the google finance chart above, the columns cdsTA and macd are identical and agree closely with Google's EMA figures. `MACD()`'s value for macd al also pretty close to GF's. And so I get

macd - signal = divergence.

However, cdoTA is way off. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong.  The `cdoTA` code doesn't pass `lag1` or `lag2` to `cdsTA`, so it just uses the default values of 12 and 26.

```
> cdoTA
function (x, lag1 = 12, lag2 = 26, lag3 = 9) 
{
    cdo = macdTA(x, lag1 = lag1, lag2 = lag2) -
           cdsTA(x, lag3 = lag3)                 # no lag1 or lag2, so...
    if (is.timeSeries(x)) 
        colnames(cdo) <- "CDO"
    cdo
}
> args(cdsTA)                                    # default arg values are used
function (x, lag1 = 12, lag2 = 26, lag3 = 9) 
NULL
```

You can define your own function `CDOTA`:

```
CDOTA <- function (x, lag1 = 12, lag2 = 26, lag3 = 9) {
    cdo = macdTA(x, lag1 = lag1, lag2 = lag2) -
           cdsTA(x, lag1 = lag1, lag2 = lag2, lag3 = lag3)
    if (is.timeSeries(x)) 
        colnames(cdo) <- "CDO"
    cdo
}
```

Or just do the subtraction yourself with the results from `TTR::MACD`.

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("IBM", source="google")
ibm <- merge(Cl(IBM), MACD(Cl(IBM), 8, 17, 9, "EMA", FALSE))
ibm$macdOsc <- ibm$macd - ibm$signal
tail(ibm)
#            IBM.Close      macd   signal    macdOsc
# 2011-02-15    162.84 1.8361263 2.643950 -0.8078238
# 2011-02-16    163.40 1.6248017 2.440120 -0.8153187
# 2011-02-17    164.24 1.5319154 2.258479 -0.7265640
# 2011-02-18    164.84 1.4965394 2.106091 -0.6095520
# 2011-02-22    161.95 1.1140192 1.907677 -0.7936578
# 2011-02-23    160.18 0.6253874 1.651219 -1.0258316
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua. That helps a lot.